# PromiseKit with Swift: terminate chain of promises

Tags: swift, promisekit

I'm trying to use PromiseKit with Swift. I am not really familiar with it, and there doesn't seem to be much information on its usage with Swift.

I can't seem to figure out how to terminate a chain of promises. As long as the last (terminal) `then` block contains a single statement, everything is fine:

```
firstly {
    // ...
}.then { obj in
    self.handleResult(obj)
}.catch { error in
    self.handleError(error)
}
```

However, if I try to add another statement, compiler complains:

```
firstly {
    // ...
}.then { obj in
    self.handleResult(obj)
    self.doSomethingDifferent(obj)
}.catch { error in // compiler error: Missing return in a closure expected to return 'AnyPromise'
    self.handleError(error)
}
```

Obviously, the solution is to return another promise, but it doesn't make sense in the terminal block. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to http://promisekit.org/PromiseKit-2.0-Released/, under **Swift Compiler Issues** section:

> The Swift compiler will often error with then. To figure out the
>   issue, first try specifying the full signature for your closures:

```
foo.then { x in
    doh()
    return bar()
}

// will need to be written as:

foo.then { obj -> Promise<Type> in
    doh()
    return bar()
}

// Because the Swift compiler cannot infer closure types very
// well yet. We hope this will be fixed.

// Watch out for  one-line closures though! Swift will
// automatically infer the types, which may confuse you:

foo.then {
    return bar()
}
```

So you'll have to change your code to:

```
firstly {
    // ...
}.then { obj -> Promise<WhateverTypeDoSomethingDifferentPromises> in
    self.handleResult(obj)
    self.doSomethingDifferent(obj)
}.catch { error in
    self.handleError(error)
}
```

Or you can use `obj -> Void` to stop the chain

Comment: _Or you can use `obj -> Void` to stop the chain_ - yes, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

```
firstly {
    // ...
}.then { obj -> Void in
    self.handleResult(obj)
    self.doSomethingDifferent(obj)
}.catch { error in
    self.handleError(error)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how is it different from the accepted one?

Comment: accepted one doesn't work, there is not return. also you wanted a void not a promise

Answer (score 0):

In PromiseKit 6.10.0 use `done` instead of `then` if you don't want to continue a chain with `Thenable`:

```
firstly {
    // ...
}.done { obj in
    self.handleResult(obj)
    self.doSomethingDifferent(obj)
}.catch { error in
    self.handleError(error)
}
```

Comment: if the break is conditional this solution is not worth

Comment: @JBarros35 What break do you mean?

Comment: @RomanPodymov  if you have the leave the chain under a condition. that's the question

Comment: @JBarros35 @rommex The question is about "what if I don't return a value from `then`". You are talking about this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907061/promisekit-cancel-a-promise.

Answer (score -2):

In Swift release 5.1 you can do that with Combine Framework, to solve this you can use the pattern Future. This is the same thing that Promise uses. Your code will look like this:

```html
final class Future<Output, Failure> where Failure : Error
```

So just to warn you about promises in Swift and new framework.

Comment: The question is about PromiseKit, not Combine.