# PromiseKit cancel a promise

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

How do I cancel a promise that has been neither fulfilled or rejected yet?

The documentation for PromiseKit talks about cancelling a promise, but I can't find a specific example of how to do this.

Given:

```
currentOperation = client.load(skip: skip, query: nil)
currentOperation!.then { (items) in
   self.processItems(items: items, skip: skip, query: query)
}.catch { (error) in
    print("failed to load items - just retrying")
    self.loadIfNeeded(skip: skip, query: query, onlyInStock: onlyInStock)
}
```

If the query changes (user enters some text in the search bar) I want to cancel and discard the `currentOperation`, starting a new promise.

Comment: There is a thread on the Promisekit github page about promise chain cancellation. Did you check [here](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/339)?

Comment: I see, thanks @ridvankucuk. I can see that it is not as trivial as I initially thought.

Comment: You would be better served to look into RxSwift, ReactiveKit, Interstellar or one of the other reactive SDKs for this sort of job.

Comment: Thanks for your advice again. Of those, do yoi have a favorite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PromiseKit 7, use `func cancellize()` to convert a `Promise` or `Guarantee` into a promise that can be cancelled:

```
currentOperation = client.load(skip: skip, query: nil)
let currentOperationCancellable = currentOperation!.then { (items) in
   self.processItems(items: items, skip: skip, query: query)
}.cancellize()
currentOperationCancellable.catch { (error) in
    print("failed to load items - just retrying")
    self.loadIfNeeded(skip: skip, query: query, onlyInStock: onlyInStock)
}
```

Use `func cancel()` or `func cancel(with:)` to cancel a cancellable `Promise` or `Guarantee`:

```
currentOperationCancellable.cancel()
currentOperationCancellable.cancel(with: NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to cancel a promise you have to reject it with any error type that conforms to `CancellableError` protocol. This way any catch block with `policy` parameter set to `allErrorsExceptCancellation` will let the error pass through.

If you need a CancellablePromise you may subclass Promise and implement a cancel() function that will reject with a `CancellableError` when called. Here is a minimal implementation:

https://gist.github.com/EfraimB/918eebdf7dd020801c72da1289c8d797

UPDATE:

Here is an update for the new PromiseKit version (6.4.1)

https://gist.github.com/EfraimB/3ac240fc6e65aa8835df073f68fe32d9

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my library CancellablePromiseKit is useful for you: https://github.com/johannesd/CancellablePromiseKit

It allows you to define a CancellablePromise similarly to how you define an ordinary Promise, with the addition of a cancel block. In that block, you write the code for cancelling the underlying task. The promise can then be cancelled by calling cancellablePromise.cancel() from the outside.

```
let cancellablePromise = CancellablePromise<String> { resolver in
    let currentOperation = client.load(skip: skip, query: nil)
    currentOperation.completion = { (value, error) in
        resolver.resolve(value, error)
    }
    return {
        // The cancel block
        currentOperation.stop()
    }
}
```

The lib also overloads when and race to cancel tasks automatically.